# ViewPager + Volley lazy load = mess

Tags: android, android-viewpager, lazy-loading, android-volley

So basically, i have a `RecyclerView` within a fragment, set within `onCreateView()`, also i've put volley request inside `onCreateView()` that updates the `Recycler adapter` with new data that is being lazy loaded from the server. Everything worked great until i started sliding between pages too fast - and since onCreateView() is being called for fragments that surround current fragment while sliding - volley sends multiple data with the same parameters to the server - and my `RecyclerView` gets same data for a couple of times (depending on how fast i slide).

I've put something like:

```
 static boolean requestAllowed = true;

 @OverRide public View onCreateView() {

 inflater etc..
 if(requestAllowed) {
 requestAllowed = false;
 sendingVolleyRequest();
 }
```

And then within `sendingVolleyRequest()`, i have put in `onResponse()` or `onErrorResponse()` `requestAllowed = true;`.

However, it gets passed by that and its sends requests regardless of that statement (probably thread issue), so i am just wondering - is there any good way of solving this, other than forbiding sending same parameters two times in a row (which will prohibit getting updates if list gets updated after i finish loading before update). Thank you in advance, and sorry for not providing code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement `onPageChangedListener()` on your viewPager and in `onPageSelected()` method send volly request.

Comment: This helped, however - i had to put conditions `requestAllowed` within Request method, not in `onCreateView()` method and worked like a charm, thank you :)